# Which condition should A satisfy - Cholesky factorization

Tags: positive-definite

I have been given some matrix A that have size nxn and is nonsingular. I have to find out which condition A should satisfy such that it has a Cholesky factorization A = LL^T.

Can someone help me with this? Because should A not just be positive definitive which it already is because A is nonsingular or am I incorrect?

Comment: Indeed : Being **symmetric** positive definite is the condition which is asked. I don't understand when you say " which is already met when A is non singular" : No ! Being positive definite means for $A$ to fulfill condition $X^TAX >0$ for all $X \ne 0$ : very few (already symmetric) matrices pass the test!!

Comment: Ahh okay, I have missed that. Thank you for clarifying it for me and answering my question. It was very helpful!!